# caching images using ajax

Tags: ajax

the div content of my web page changes dynamically. The images used in dynamic html are currently on server.is there any way i can cahce those images to have better experience when content of div are change

Answer (score 2):

You can preload your images on the `onLoad` event for better performance. To preload an image use the `Image` object:

```
var anImage = new Image(width, height);
```

The above creates an object in memory whose properties are empty. But you can then assign an image URL to the object's src property:

```
var anImage = new Image(100, 200);
anImage.src = "imageFile.gif";
```

You then assign the `src` property of this stored image to the `src` property of your `<img>` element that appears in the page:

```
document.images["someImage"].src = anImage.src; // preloaded image
```